# Django Paypal Integration createOrder curl

Tags: django, curl, paypal

I'm trying to implement PayPal in Django without any SDK or package.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/create-order/

Want to rewrite this cURL to Python

```sh
 curl -v -X POST https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders \ 
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer Access-Token" \
-d '{
  "intent": "CAPTURE",
  "purchase_units": [
    {
      "amount": {
        "currency_code": "USD",
        "value": "100.00"
      }
    }
  ]
}'
```

My current code:

```py
t = gettoken()
d = {"intent": "CAPTURE","purchase_units": [{"amount": {"currency_code": "USD","value": "100.00"}}]}
h = {"Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer "+t}
r = requests.post('https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders', headers=h, data=d).json()
```

My Error:

```py
Internal Server Error: /createOrder
.....
AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'items'
```

The Bearer Token is fine.

Any idea? What am I missing?

Comment: The correct header is `{"Content-Type": "application/json", "Authorization": "Bearer "+t}`. The current one you have is actually a `set` and not a `dict` hence the error

Comment: Thanks. Now i'm getting '{'name': 'INVALID_REQUEST', 'message': 'Request is not well-formed, syntactically incorrect, or violates schema.', 'debug_id': '252e2f9a9587d', 'details': [{'location': 'body', 'issue': 'MALFORMED_REQUEST_JSON', 'description': 'The request JSON is not well formed.'}], 'links': [{'href': 'https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#error-MALFORMED_REQUEST_JSON', 'rel': 'information_link', 'encType': 'application/json'}]}  so is there any error in my d part?

Comment: It looks ok. Does it work with curl?

Answer (score 0):

```
 d = {"intent": "CAPTURE","purchase_units": [{"amount": {"currency_code": "USD","value": "100.00"}}]}
 h = {"Content-Type": "application/json", "Authorization": "Bearer "+t}
 r = requests.post('https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders', headers=h, json=d).json()
```

Works.